# What is the difference between the table element and CSS display:table

Tags: css, css-tables

Is there a difference between table element and CSS display table.
Which is faster when draw by browser?

Comment: It is the same. display:table makes the browser to see the DOM element as a table which means that in general case it will spend more time than usual to calculate width-s of `TD` or equivalents to `TD` which are inside container..

Comment: @Mr Lister: original revision

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617895/actual-table-vs-div-table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629857/displaytable-versus-using-tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681962/html-table-vs-css-display-table, ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are differences between using `<table>` and using `<div style="display:table">`.

## Differences in styling

Every element has its own default set of styles. Changing one style property (in this case, `display`) doesn't change the other properties, so you'll have to put those in explicitly if you want to emulate a real table.

**`Property       in table    in div (with display:table)`**          
`border-spacing 2px         0px`                                  
`box-sizing     border-box¹ content-box`                          
`border-color   #808080²    same as currentColor`                 
  **`Property       in caption  in div (with display:table-caption)`**  
`text-align     center      start`                                
  **`Property       in tbody    in div (with display:table-row-group)`**
`vertical-align middle      baseline`                             
`border-color   #808080²    same as currentColor`                 
  **`Property       in th       in div (with display:table-cell)`**     
`font-weight    700         400`                                  
`padding:       1px         0px`                                  
`text-align     center      start`                                
`vertical-align middle      baseline`                             
  **`Property       in td       in div (with display:table-cell)`**     
`padding:       1px         0px`                                  
`vertical-align middle      baseline`

¹ Mozilla only
² Chrome only

So a stylesheet for a proper CSS table needs to contain at least the following:

```css
.table {display:table; border-spacing:2px;}
.caption {display: table-caption; text-align:center;}
.colgroup {display:table-column-group}
.col {display:table-column}
.thead {display:table-header-group; vertical-align:middle;}
.tbody {display:table-row-group; vertical-align:middle;}
.tfoot {display:table-footer-group; vertical-align:middle;}
.tr {display:table-row;}
.th {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding:1px;
     text-align:center; font-weight:700;}
.td {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding:1px;}
```

## Differences in attributes

Table elements have more attributes than plain divs.

**`table`**                                                           
`border     Draws outset border, and inset borders around all cells` 
`sortable   Enables a sorting interface for the table`            
  **`colgroup`**                                                        
`span       Number of columns spanned by the element`             
  **`col`**                                                             
`span       Number of columns spanned by the element`             
  **`th`**                                                              
`colspan    Number of columns that the cell is to span`           
`rowspan    Number of rows that the cell is to span`              
`headers    The header cells for this cell`                       
`scope      Specifies which cells the header cell applies to`     
`abbr       Alternative label to use for the header cell`         
`sorted     Column sort direction and ordinality`                 
  **`td`**                                                              
`colspan    Number of columns that the cell is to span`           
`rowspan    Number of rows that the cell is to span`              
`headers    The header cells for this cell`

## Differences in markup

In tables, the elements `colgroup`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `th` and `td` have optional end tags. With `div`, you have no such luxury and you will need to write out all end tags in full.
In addition, `tbody` also has an optional start tag. That means a table with only `tr` and no `tbody` elements in the markup will have a tbody in the DOM tree.

This may not seem to matter much, but there are subtle differences in the results under some circumstances.
Given the above CSS and the following markup

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="vertical-align:inherit">1</td>
  <td>1<br>2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<div class="table">
 <div class="tr">
  <div class="td" style="vertical-align:inherit">1</div>
  <div class="td">1<br>2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the table cells in the actual table will be vertically aligned to the middle (because they inherit from the `tbody`), but not in the CSS table, where there is no tbody to inherit from. Keep that in mind when writing your HTML.

## Differences in the JavaScript interface

Table nodes have more properties:
`createCaption()`, `deleteCaption()`, `createTHead()`, `deleteTHead()`, `createTFoot()`, `deleteTFoot()`, `createTBody()`, `insertRow()`, `deleteRow()`, `caption`, `tHead`, `tFoot`, `tBodies[]`, `rows[]`, `border`, `frame`, `rules`, `summary`, `width`, `bgColor`, `cellPadding`, `cellSpacing` which, hopefully, speak for themselves.

That's about it. Differences in performance are negligible.

Comment: Thank you . That helped me a lot.